# How to pass a value of type `Union[bytes, str]` to function taking `AnyStr`

Tags: python, types, type-theory

Suppose I have a couple of functions:

```py
from typing import Union, AnyStr
def f(x: Union[bytes, str]):
  return g(x)
def g(x: AnyStr):
  return x
```

Running `mypy` on this causes an error

```
:3: error: Value of type variable "AnyStr" of "g" cannot be "Union[bytes, str]"
```

This is fixable by doing the following:

```py
from typing import Union, AnyStr
def f(x: Union[bytes, str]):
        if isinstance(x, bytes):
                g(x)
        elif isinstance(x, str):
                g(x)
def g(x: AnyStr):
        return x
```

Surely a type which is either `bytes` or `str` (a `Union[bytes, str]` must either be bytes or `str`, not both) can be passed to a function taking `AnyStr`?

Why isn't this the case?

Comment: This [issue seems relevant](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1533) apparently it's an open bug.

Comment: strictly speaking, I guess they aren't equivalent. For example, for `x: Union[bytes, str]`, then `x = 'hello'; x = b'world'` can work, but for `AnyStr`, it can't

Comment: Yeah, but in this particular case at the point at which I call `f(x)` I *think* that `x` must either be `str` or `bytes` – it can't be both.

Comment: right, my point is that you can't just do a simple substitution, but yeah, the type-checker should be able to see this case works but clearly. maybe next version they'll add that enhancement

Comment: can you try if `typing.cast()` work? Try to cast it to `AnyStr`.

Comment: @RonieMartinez FWIW I tried the cast, but it's just more mypy confusion: `error: Redundant cast to typing.AnyStr?; error: Type variable "typing.AnyStr" is unbound`